# Store a number that is longer than type long in Java

Tags: java

How can I store a number that is longer than the long type (MAX: 9223372036854775807) in Java?

For example the number 9223372036854775820.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is very few cases where you need longer integer types.  Cryptography is one, but I don't suggest you write this yourself. Even BigDecimal only uses these selectively in Java 7.

Answer (score 31):

Use `BigInteger` if you work with a long and use `BigDecimal` if you work with floatingpoint numbers. The `BigInteger` can be as big as you want, till there is not enough RAM.

Example:

```
    BigInteger bd = new BigInteger("922337203685477582012312321");
    System.out.println(bd.multiply(new BigInteger("15")));
    System.out.println(bd);
```

Output:

```
13835058055282163730184684815
922337203685477582012312321
```

But have to use the `BigInteger` methods to do calculations and in the example you see that `BigInteger` is immutable.

Answer (score 2):

You must use [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) to store values that exceed the max value of long.

Comment: Strictly, this is incorrect.  There are other ways he could do it ... so "must" is an over-reach.

Comment: @StephenC It would be helpful had you given a solution rather than what you posted.

Comment: @NinjaElvis - Why would it have been helpful? There were already 4 correct solutions. What would be the point of posting a duplicate?  For a question that was a duplicate in the first place?   I was simply pointing out that Kevin was incorrect in asserting that BigInteger is the only way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a BigInteger type.

Answer (score -1):

Please consider the Java API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Comment: Why BigDecimal? The number seems to be an integral.

Comment: @assylias: He can use BigInteger too, but that should be obvious, when one reads the API.